# SSRS AutoRefresh only one time

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

Is there anyway to run an expression under the `AutoRefresh` property in SSRS 2013 that will run the `AutoRefresh` property one time only?

Comment: Theoretically, I think this can be done using custom code and an expression on the refresh